# Dynamics CRM 2011 - "An Error Occurs" when I try to open a entity that was created through a plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a plugin that creates an instance of a custom entity. The create seems to work without any errors but when I try to open the entity in a form I get "An error has occurred", with no further explanation and no error text to download. How do I debug the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went and removed all of the fields but one. Tested the form and then started adding them back in, testing as I went. I did that until I found the field with the problem, which was a floating point field.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabled [trace](http://exploringxrm.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/enabling-trace-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011/) or use this [tool](http://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com/), to get more information.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: Sorry but the question is. "How do i debug the problem?" Which is better answer?